# upload and get chunks from GridFS (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, chunks

I'm new in `mongoDB`, and I try to upload a file to `GridFS` with chunks. Meaning, I get a file from my client divided into chunks, and I want to upload it to `mongoDB`, so a file would be a collection of chunks.

In other words, I want to implement random access in gridFS.

How can I do it? and how I can get this file (which again, divided into parts in my mongo.db. is the Id would be the same?)

The application is written in node.js

Comment: See the node.js mongodb driver docs - http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html

Comment: @maerics: Thanks. It shows how to get the chunk collection, but it doesn't show how to store one.

Comment: @OrSmith: GridFS would store the file by breaking it in chunks. When you are saying that you want to implement random access, how do you wish to access exactly? You just want the ability to get a random file chunk? If yes, why not use a GridFS index?

Comment: why do you get the file from your client in chunks?  or do you mean that your application splits it into chunks before uploading them to mongodb and if so, why?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: My client sends the file in chunks, due to performance issue. My server must assume that the client send the file in chunks.

Comment: @displayName: My client send the file in chunks. this process happens *before* the GridFS breaks the file into chunks. How gridFS index can help me in this case?

Comment: @OrSmith: Are the chunks already in Bson format?

Comment: @displayName: No. The client is uploading a file in chunks. It can be PDF, doc, jpeg, or any other format. If it was BSON there is a way to do it? If it not BSON, can I convert it and then do the random access (which again, I don't know how to do it).

Comment: Weel for now i can deliver you the bad news that you can't store these chunks to MongoDB. They *have* to be Bson. You will surely need to convert the chunks to Bson if you wish to store them on Mongo.

Comment: @displayName: there is any way to convert it? If so, how can I store it?

Comment: @displayName: In other words, let assume that the chunks are BSON. can I upload chunks to mongoDB?

Comment: @OrSmith: If you have Bson chunks and want to upload them, you will have to create one more data structure (i.e. index) for retrieving your file by pulling out all of its chunks. So you are effectively trying to implement what MongoDB has already done. Better would be to assemble the file and let MongoDB break it and store on GridFS for you.

Comment: @displayName: Thanks. But assemble and then split it again is less efficient, no?

Comment: @OrSmith: But it is more efficient than reinventing the wheel. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in node sequential chunks of data are handled using [streams](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), if in this case if you are dealing with streams, then [gridfs-stream module](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream) is your best bet. Check the example and also the [stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook). you can just write a file by piping a stream into it or read a file by piping it into another stream.

If you don't have a stream already, you can also use it manually. For writing data you can just use nodes `.write` and `.end` methods:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

// create or use an existing mongodb-native db instance
var db = new mongo.Db('yourDatabaseName', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));
var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);

// streaming to gridfs
var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename: 'my_file.txt'
});

writestream.write('this is a line\n');
writestream.write('second line coming some time after\n');
writestream.write('last line');
writestream.end();// Add the EOF marker and finish the file writing.
```

Or read from the file:

```
var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
  filename: 'my_file.txt'
});

readstream.on('data', function (data) {
    // We got a buffer of data...
});
readstream.on('end', function () {
    // File finished reading...
});
```

Note that only the old API works here. For new api you have to wrap the stream.

You can pass a `chunkSize` option, if you want to change the amount of data being read everytime.

Now if your data is not coming in/going out sequentially or you want to get closer to the metal(more low level), you can use the [mongodb gridstore API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html).

For writing files, you should use the write method of a gridstore instance:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {
  // Our file ID
  var fileId = new ObjectID();

  // Open a new file
  var gridStore = new GridStore(db, fileId, 'w');

  // Open the new file
  gridStore.open(function(err, gridStore) {

    // Write a text string
    gridStore.write('Hello world', function(err, gridStore) {

      // Write a buffer
      gridStore.write(new Buffer('Buffer Hello world'), function(err, gridStore) {

        // Close the file...
        gridStore.close(function(err, result) {});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

You can change the writing position by calling the `.seek` method if you want random writes.

For reading, you can use the `.read` method which is almost counterpart of `.write` method:

```
gs.seek(0, function() {
  // Read 1024 bytes...
  gs.read(1024, function(err, data) {
    // Now go to position 2048
    gs.seek(2048, function () {
      // Read another 1024 bytes...
      gs.read(1024, function(err, data) {
      });      
    });
  });
});
```

There's also `GridStore.read` method. Which is a higher level method for the above functions:

```
// Read 1024 bytes starting from the byte 2048.
GridStore.read(db, 'file1', 1024, 2048, function (err, data) {

});
```

I hope that can help you. That's all there is to reading/writing in chunks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to be sure before I accept the answer - So GridFS support writing in chunks? As you say, I can use the `.seek` option (If there is any example, it would be lovely) and then I can write the chunks I get from the client. I ask it because In the comments before, displayName suggest that it would be better to assemble the file and let MongoDB break it and store on GridFS for you. But with the `seek` option, I can write the chunks directly, without assemble it before. I correct?

Comment: Hi is there a similar approach in c# driver?